# Curve Fitting and Multiple Experiments

Tags: experimental-physics, data-analysis

Say I do an an experiment 5 times, each of which gives you a list of data points. Do I fit a curve to each one separately and then average the parameters and their uncertainties? Or do I take the average of all the experiments and then do fit a single curve to that?

Comment: That depends: are the experiments sufficiently identical to group them? You pretty well have to understand the whole experiment and analysis that you are doing to answer that question... You'd prefer to do the latter if it is safe.

Comment: Do you mean if the experiments are set up exactly the same? So if I'm taking the absorption spectrum of a material multiple times, I should average it out, and then fit a curve?

Comment: It *depends*. Is your instrument subject to run-to-run variations that require separate analysis or not. You have to understand before you can answer the question. You could be lucky here, but I can't tell you.

Comment: So as long as you can ensure the instrument is not effected by the experiment, you should take the mean?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Assuming that your **5 experiments are independent of each other** (independent would mean for instance that you let the exact same stone drop from the exact same height (as is feasible in practice) drop 5 times), you have to fit the curve to each of the 5 experiments and then extract the **quantity** that you are looking for from each individual curve.

**Step 2:** Next you compute the mean and the standard deviation of the 5 individual quantities you extracted this way. The more measurements you make, the smaller your standard deviation should become.

Those two steps above cannot be a substitute for learning error analysis properly. Please do that.